# Why Kotlin doesn't allow assignments as expressions?

Tags: java, kotlin

Coming from Java, I was surprised to find out that Kotlin doesn't allow assignments as expressions.

Is there a reason for that?

**Java** (Works)

```
    @Test
    public void test_x() {
        List<String> elements = null;
        for (final String x : (elements = List.<String>of("1", "2"))) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

**Kotlin** (Compile-time error)

```
    /*Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context*/
    @Test
    fun test_x() {
        var elements: List<String> = listOf()
        for (x in (elements = listOf("1", "2"))) {
            println(x)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even in the Java code you don't need the extra variable. What is the purpose of "elements"?

Comment: The example is written to demonstrate (and test) that it's compilable.

Answer (score 9):

The only people who can answer this question are the designers of Kotlin. However, we can make some educated guesses:

- Assignment is a *fundamentally imperative* operation. In pure functional programming, there are no assignments, in fact, the *very idea* of "assignment" doesn't even make sense in FP. Assignment is about changing the state of the world: before the assignment, variable `foo` was bound to value `bar`, after the assignment, it is bound to value `baz`. Operations that change the state of the world (e.g. printing, reading from the console), generally have a `Unit` or `void` type and/or are *statements*. (Depending on which one of those your programming language actually has.)
- Accidentally assigning when you mean to test for equality, is a *really common* mistake. (Just within the last couple of hours, I saw at least three different questions on Stack Overflow that were caused by that mistake.) If assignments are statements, that mistake simply *cannot happen*.
- Kotlin was influenced by Scala, even if in a lot of cases in how *not* to do things. In Scala, like several newer languages, assignments are "statements". (Technically, Scala doesn't have statements, everything is an expression, but assignments evaluate to `()` which is the singleton inhabitant of the `Unit` type which denotes a useless return value.)

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin allows named arguments, which also uses the `=` as separator. A function `fun foo(bar: Int)` might be called as `foo(42)` or `foo(bar = 42)`. Thus, assignment cannot occur within expressions without introducing substantial ambiguity. (Other languages can avoid this by using a different syntax for named arguments, by having a separate inline assignment operator, or by requiring inline assignments to be parenthesized, e.g. `var x = 0; foo(bar = (x = 42))`.)

There's also a line of thinking in functional-inspired languages that assignments are side effects and should therefore be discouraged and made more explicit. Ideally, variables are assigned exactly once, during initialization (as with Kotlin's `val`).

Assignments in expressions are mostly useful in control flow constructs, e.g something like `while (it = next()) ...`. Maybe Kotlin will get suitable syntax in the future.